# add a character C in a column if that column is blank

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have some files that look as follows. I need to add a character 'C' in the fifth column if that column is blank. I prefer inplace editing.

```
1   87 E P              0   0  131      0, 0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0   0.000 360.0 360.0 360.0 150.0    7.2   83.8   79.2
2   88 E V        +     0   0  136      1,-0.1     2,-0.5     3,-0.0     0, 0.0   0.993 360.0  80.8 -61.8 -61.8    7.7   80.9   76.8
3   89 E K  S    S+     0   0  195      2,-0.0     2,-0.3     0, 0.0    -1,-0.1  -0.222  77.4 108.3 -45.5  95.3    5.5   82.5   74.2
4   90 E R  S    S-     0   0  153     -2,-0.5     2,-0.5     2,-0.0     0, 0.0  -0.864  72.2-119.8-173.3 140.8    8.2   84.8   72.9
5  191 E R       -     0   0  202     -2,-0.3     2,-0.2     1,-0.0    -2,-0.0  -0.772  46.1-115.0 -83.4 130.6   10.4   85.4   70.0
6   92 E L  H     -     0   0  109     -2,-0.5     2,-0.5     1,-0.1    -1,-0.0  -0.499  24.5-142.8 -70.2 134.3   14.0   85.3   71.3
7   93 E D        +     0   0  126     -2,-0.2    -1,-0.1     1,-0.1     0, 0.0  -0.852  36.1 149.0-101.0 126.6   15.9   88.6   71.1
8   94 E L              0   0  140     -2,-0.5    -1,-0.1     0, 0.0    -2,-0.0   0.735 360.0 360.0-125.7 -35.5   19.6   88.3   70.3
9   95 E E              0   0  235      0, 0.0    -2,-0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0   0.494 360.0 360.0  -8.6 360.0   21.0   91.3   68.3
```

Desired Output

```
1   87 E P  C           0   0  131      0, 0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0   0.000 360.0 360.0 360.0 150.0    7.2   83.8   79.2
2   88 E V  C      +    0   0  136      1,-0.1     2,-0.5     3,-0.0     0, 0.0   0.993 360.0  80.8 -61.8 -61.8    7.7   80.9   76.8
3   89 E K  S    S+     0   0  195      2,-0.0     2,-0.3     0, 0.0    -1,-0.1  -0.222  77.4 108.3 -45.5  95.3    5.5   82.5   74.2
4   90 E R  S    S-     0   0  153     -2,-0.5     2,-0.5     2,-0.0     0, 0.0  -0.864  72.2-119.8-173.3 140.8    8.2   84.8   72.9
5  191 E R  C     -     0   0  202     -2,-0.3     2,-0.2     1,-0.0    -2,-0.0  -0.772  46.1-115.0 -83.4 130.6   10.4   85.4   70.0
6   92 E L  H     -     0   0  109     -2,-0.5     2,-0.5     1,-0.1    -1,-0.0  -0.499  24.5-142.8 -70.2 134.3   14.0   85.3   71.3
7   93 E D  C      +    0   0  126     -2,-0.2    -1,-0.1     1,-0.1     0, 0.0  -0.852  36.1 149.0-101.0 126.6   15.9   88.6   71.1
8   94 E L  C           0   0  140     -2,-0.5    -1,-0.1     0, 0.0    -2,-0.0   0.735 360.0 360.0-125.7 -35.5   19.6   88.3   70.3
9   95 E E  C           0   0  235      0, 0.0    -2,-0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0   0.494 360.0 360.0  -8.6 360.0   21.0   91.3   68.3
```

Comment: Most solutions require that your data has consistent field separators like spaces or at least consistent length of fields or sets of fields. If somewhere in your data two fields merges as one due to one having a large value, or a field or a set of fields changes the expectedly fixed length, that row would be misinterpreted, and could only be fixed by applying conditional checkings as well. And there's no way we could know that unless you add more information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{a=substr($0, 17, 1);a=(a~/[[:alpha:]]/)?a:"C";print substr($0,1, 16) a substr($0,18)}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not obvious from your example how you define "fifth column". If your columns are fixed width, the "fifth column" seems to correspond with the thirteenth character position.

If that is correct, then on any line starting with twelve characters and a blank, replace with those same twelve characters and a C.

```
sed -i 's/^\(............\) /\1C/' filename
```

If you are e.g. on OSX, you need `-i ''` because the `-i` option requires a mandatory parameter on that platform. If your `sed` lacks `-i` altogether, try the equivalent Perl script:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.{12}) /$1C/' filename
```

If your data is not fixed width throughout, it would seem to be impossible to deduce what exactly to replace, unless you can formulate your data description in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
use strict; use warnings;
while (<>) {
 my @f = split(/,/);
 my @v=split(/(\s+)/,$f[0]); 
 $v[7] = "  C     " if @v < 19; 
 $v[7].= "      "   if @v < 17; 
 $f[0] = join("", @v);
 print  join(",", @f);
}
```

*Execution:*

```
perl script.pl input
```

*Output:*

```
1   87 E P  C           0   0  131      0, 0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0   0.000 360.0 360.0 360.0 150.0    7.2   83.8   79.2
2   88 E V  C     +     0   0  136      1,-0.1     2,-0.5     3,-0.0     0, 0.0   0.993 360.0  80.8 -61.8 -61.8    7.7   80.9   76.8
3   89 E K  S    S+     0   0  195      2,-0.0     2,-0.3     0, 0.0    -1,-0.1  -0.222  77.4 108.3 -45.5  95.3    5.5   82.5   74.2
4   90 E R  S    S-     0   0  153     -2,-0.5     2,-0.5     2,-0.0     0, 0.0  -0.864  72.2-119.8-173.3 140.8    8.2   84.8   72.9
5  191 E R  C     -     0   0  202     -2,-0.3     2,-0.2     1,-0.0    -2,-0.0  -0.772  46.1-115.0 -83.4 130.6   10.4   85.4   70.0
6   92 E L  H     -     0   0  109     -2,-0.5     2,-0.5     1,-0.1    -1,-0.0  -0.499  24.5-142.8 -70.2 134.3   14.0   85.3   71.3
7   93 E D  C     +     0   0  126     -2,-0.2    -1,-0.1     1,-0.1     0, 0.0  -0.852  36.1 149.0-101.0 126.6   15.9   88.6   71.1
8   94 E L  C           0   0  140     -2,-0.5    -1,-0.1     0, 0.0    -2,-0.0   0.735 360.0 360.0-125.7 -35.5   19.6   88.3   70.3
9   95 E E  C           0   0  235      0, 0.0    -2,-0.0     0, 0.0     0, 0.0   0.494 360.0 360.0  -8.6 360.0   21.0   91.3   68.3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run your code, the space between the columns are too large in the output.It's not like the output you got. How can I reduce the space? My OS is ubuntu 12.04.